# .exe file crashes within seconds

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to coding, I started with Python and Selenium, I managed to write a code, that automatically navigates through a website and downloads a .xls file, everything worked perfectly. When I converted it to a .exe file with pyinstaller, again it works perfectly in my desktop. But when I share it with my friends and ask them to run, it closes immediately within seconds.

Comment: If your friend starts the exe file from cmd, it will print error messages so you can better find out what/where it is going wrong. Though, you might have to generate the .exe file with the -d (debug) option for that, I can't remember from the top of my head.

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your friends are missing dll's that you have on your machine. From your description it is difficult to say what exactly is missing.

I was not using `Pyinstaller` but I'd guess there should be an option to link dll's statically. If such option does not exist then you will need to figure out what dll's are being dynamically linked and you will have to distribute them to your friends with your executable.

Possibly the most simple way would be to ask your friends to install whatever programs you have installed (i.e. `Python`, `Selenium`, `Pyinstaller`)

---

Edit

I encourage you to actually read `Pyinstaller` documentation, it's really great resurce. I found two interesting avenues you can try to follow. One is to use `--add-binary` to hopefully include all your dependencies in the bundle. Second is to [check windows section of documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows) as there is some interesting information in this paragraph.

Comment: I'm unable to share the codes b/c it has some private files related to my work.
Aslo, I compiled it with Pyinstaller as a onefile pacakge with --onefile, even if we use onefile do I need to share all the dll's to the end user.